# '“1” is not a valid UUID.' Django

Tags: django, uuid, validationerror

Getting this error when i try to delete a reservation from a user account on my restuarant booking app.

Tried a few things to no avail so if anyone can help I'd greatly apprecaite it.

Code is as follows:

Model.py file:

```
class Reservations(models.Model):

    """ reservation form categories and attributes """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phoneNumberRegex], max_length=16, 
unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.CharField(choices=time_options, default="12pm", max_length=10)
    number_of_party = models.IntegerField(choices=party_size, default=1)
    reservation_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, 
editable=False)
```

Views.py file:

```
class DeleteReservationView(LoginRequiredMixin, 
UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    """ A view to delete an reservation """
    model = Reservations
    success_url = "/reservations_account/"

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user == self.get_object().user
```

HTML file:

```
{% for reservation in reservations %}

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{% static 'images/restuarant.jpg' %}" alt="Card restuarant image">
    <div class="card-body">
        <ul>
            <li>{{ reservation.name | capfirst }}</li>
            <li>{{ reservation.phone_number }}</li>
            <li>{{ reservation.email }}</li>
            <li>{{ reservation.date }}</li>
            <li>{{ reservation.time }}</li>
            <li>{{ reservation.number_of_party }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="{% url 'edit_reservation' user.id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Edit</a>
<a href="{% url 'delete_reservation' user.id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Delete</a>
```

Not sure where the 1 is even coming from in this instance.
If you need to see more code ask and i'll edit the post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posting the model definition is good (we see `reservation_id` is an `UUIDField`), but only half the needed information (we can't see how you are deleting a reservation, if deletion is even what causes the error). So yes, more code is necessary to determine the cause of the error (except for the trivial observation that you are obviously trying to access the reservation `1`, which is not a valid value of an `UUIDField`). Show the exact error, and the code that the error points to (with a nice comment "error on this line").

Comment: added views.py and html file. Let me know if I should add more. Thanks

Comment: If I am not misinterpreting things, you are deleting the reservation `user.id`. My guess is, your user ID is `1`, and the code should really try to send `reservation.id` instead.

Comment: Ya definitely missed that. Been a long day. Now i have another error I need to tackle so can't check that that even worked but logically makes sense! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code but instead of UUIDField use AutoField
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField
'1' is probaby because UUID generated this as id.
But After all i think better version is to use AutoField